# Split digits from a string between two special characters in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
"Transaction against  Invoice No #100084# entered and 2 more pending"
```

This is the string and how can i split the digit inside two character(`#` `#`) ie:100084

Comment: You want to split or you want to get the string between `#`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char[] arr=("#100084#").Replace("#","").ToCharArray()

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

`string[] values = Regex.Matches(msgText, @"\#.*?\#").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`

EDIT:

`msgText` is the string input. This array will contain the string with # character. `#10824#`. you can replace the same

Answer (score 0):

```
"Transaction against Invoice No #100084# entered and 2 more pending".Split('#')[1]
```